# What is this ID that you can retreive from a Google App Script UrlFetchApp request?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, http-headers, user-agent

A pretty straightforward question.

What is `UAEmdDd8-EFiXubNCcQqNSsoe9JR3TFSawg` ID from `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd8-EFiXubNCcQqNSsoe9JR3TFSawg)` that can be gained from a Google App Script `UrlFetchApp` request?

## Background

I want to restrict request from any client other than Google App Script request to my server, and I decided to analyze the request header from Google App Script UrlFetchApp request, to which I get this result (using NGROK).

```
Host: dbc2-103-154-151-44.ngrok.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: UAEmdDd8-EFiXubNCcQqNSsoe9JR3TFSawg)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Forwarded-For: <hidden>
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
```

I decided to use User-Agent to restrict other requests, but I have questions on whether the ID in question is a unique identifier of the script file or not.

Comment: @Tanaike nope, I just wanted to know the ID and what it represent for. If it fits in my project I intend it to restrict by Library, so copying code is not allowed kinda deal. But if it's randomized it's fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have investigated `User-Agent` of UrlFetchApp before. In that case, I understood that it seems that the value of `UAEmdD###` like `UAEmdDd8-EFiXubNCcQqNSsoe9JR3TFSawg` is the unique value depending on the Google Apps Script project. For example, it is considered the following situation.

1. Create a new Google Apps Script project of a standalone type and UrlFetchApp is used, `User-Agent` is as follows.

   ```
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: {###ID1###})
   ```
2. Create another new Google Apps Script project of a standalone type and UrlFetchApp is used, `User-Agent` is as follows.

   ```
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: {###ID2###})
   ```
3. Create a new Google Apps Script project of a container-bound script type on Google Spreadsheet, and UrlFetchApp is used, `User-Agent` is as follows.

   ```
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: {###ID3###})
   ```

Here, it seems that when UrlFetchApp is used in the same Google Apps Script project, the same `User-Agent` with `{###}` is always used.

From this situation, for example, when you want to permit the request from only the specific Google Apps Script project by `User-Agent` at the server side, please set a value like `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: {###ID###})`. By this, only the specific Google Apps Script project can access the server.

On the other hand, when you want to permit the request from the Google Apps Script project by `User-Agent`, please set a value like  `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com` by removing the ID. By this, only the users using UrlFetchApp can access the server.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether this specification is changed in the future update. So, when you confirmed that the restriction of `User-Agent` was not your expected result after you set it, please confirm the value of `User-Agent` again.

Comment: I did the same test as @Tanaike-san and I got the same result, not sure what the ID is in itself but some kind of unique identifier. I also tested revoking the access token and sign-in once more and the ID was the same.

Comment: @Giselle Valladares Thank you for your support. In my case, I had a server that I permit only my Google Apps Script. At that time, I thought that using `User-Agent` is suitable rather than the request body and the query parameter. From this experience, I proposed this answer. In this case, it seems that even when the deployment ID is changed, the ID of `User-Agent` is not changed.

Comment: Yeah you pretty much on point all of my questions. I wonder if by making a project as a Library and then using it changes it's ID or not. But overall the remove id part is the one I was looking for, but if I can somehow track the ID back to the project or limit ID by the library, that would be extra cool. Appreciate it.